# Can you remove the "1.6.2 is Available" nag message in older versions of Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Recently I upgraded to the newest version of Minecraft only to find out that it's not compatible with a few of my favorite mods that I use. So I got my backup 1.5.2 jar, and used a custom launcher ([Magic Launcher](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/939149-launcher-magic-launcher-117-mods-options-profiles-news/)), and everything works fine.

The only issue is that when I go to the screen there is a nagging message saying that 1.6.2 is available for download. Can I get rid of it somehow or what?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The game checks the following URL before showing the reminder for manual download:

http://assets.minecraft.net/1_6_has_been_released.flag

If this URL is blocked for the client or returns empty content, the notice will not appear. This can be achieved by configuring a firewall or a proxy. For instructions on how to do that, you would receive more competent responses on superuser.com.

Comment: How would I go about doing that using the hosts file?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use the hosts file for that - the game may need assets.minecraft.net to be accessible.

Comment: Your router may be able to perform this service.

Answer (score -1):

what worked for me is disconnect to the internet and it will go away. I had the problem with the scmowns mod pack. if your trying to connect to that, reconnect to the internet and quickly click on it before it comes back!